# Concurrency/Multithreading: Is it possible to generate the same output this way?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, mutex

One thread is supposed to count up, the other down. Output varies but it generally is able to print the countUp() portion fine, followed by some flaws in the countDown() portion. Initially, I determined that the problem was that both the threads were fighting for the cout resource. This I thought would be resolved with shared_print() and mutex. However, output still varies and I'm frankly not wrapping my head around this concurrency/multithreading stuff. My main question is, is it even possible to generate the same output, or will it always vary in some way? Thanks in advance.

```
mutex mu;
int counter= 0;

int main()
{
   
    thread t1(countUp);     //t1 starts running
    thread t2(countDown);   //t2 starts running
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}

//Counts up from 0 to 20
void countUp()
{
    while(counter < 20)
    {
        counter++;
        shared_print(string("Counting Up: "), counter);
        //counter++;
    }
}

//Counts down from 20 to 0
void countDown()
{
   
   while(counter > 0)
   {
       
       //counter--;
       shared_print(string("Counting Down: "), counter);
       counter--;
   }
}

//Prints both of the counts
void shared_print(string description, int number)
{
    lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mu);
    //mu.lock();
    cout << description << number << endl;
    //mu.unlock();
}
```

Output varies from this:

```
Counting Up: 1
Counting Up: 2
Counting Up: 3
Counting Up: 4
      .
      .
      .
Counting Up: 20
```

to this(notice the 1 in place of 20 at beginning of countdown):

```
Counting Up: 1
Counting Up: 2
Counting Up: 3
Counting Up: 4
Counting Up: 5
Counting Up: 6
Counting Up: 7
Counting Up: 8
Counting Up: 9
Counting Up: 10
Counting Up: 11
Counting Up: 12
Counting Up: 13
Counting Up: 14
Counting Up: 15
Counting Up: 16
Counting Up: 17
Counting Up: 18
Counting Up: 19
Counting Up: 20
Counting Down: 1
Counting Down: 19
Counting Down: 18
Counting Down: 17
Counting Down: 16
Counting Down: 15
Counting Down: 14
Counting Down: 13
Counting Down: 12
Counting Down: 11
Counting Down: 10
Counting Down: 9
Counting Down: 8
Counting Down: 7
Counting Down: 6
Counting Down: 5
Counting Down: 4
Counting Down: 3
Counting Down: 2
Counting Down: 1
```

Comment: Your threads have a data-race when it does `counter++` and `counter--`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is a mutex a viable solution for that?

Comment: Should be. You can probably use the same one you already have, possibly using a single lock for both the variable modification and the printing.

Comment: What is the expected output? Why do you use multithreading?

Comment: @ThomasSablik The expected output is basically the second second output I have in my post with a 20 instead of a 1 at the start of the count down. Not sure why it is starting with 1 and then going to 19. I'm using multithreading because I'm preparing for an assignment that is similar in nature.

Comment: You want to call functions in seperated threads but you want them to run in a specific order. I don't understand why you use multithreading. _"Is it possible to generate the same output this way?"_ I think no, it's not possible this way. You would have to coordinate the threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Condition variable to wait, The wait operations atomically release the mutex.

```
     mutex mu;
        atomic<int> counter = 0;
        condition_variable m_cvO;
        
       //Counts up from 0 to 20
void countUp()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mu);
    m_cvO.wait(lck, [&]() {
        return counter < 20;
        });
    while (counter < 20)
    {
        counter++;
        shared_print(string("Counting Up: "), counter);
        //counter++;
    }
    m_cvO.notify_all();
   
}
    
       //Counts down from 20 to 0
    void countDown()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mu);
        m_cvO.wait(lck, [&]() {
            return counter > 0;
            });
        while (counter > 0)
        {
    
            //counter--;
            shared_print(string("Counting Down: "), counter);
            counter--;
        }
        m_cvO.notify_all();
       
    }
    
    //Prints both of the counts
    void shared_print(string description, int number)
    {
      
        //mu.lock();
        cout << description << number << endl;
        //mu.unlock();
    }
```

Comment: Using atomic<int> was giving me the following error: "Copying variable of type 'atomic<int>' invokes deleted constructor." So, I just kept it as an int and it worked perfectly! Thank you!